# parse-stack `has_many` association use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parse-server

I am using [parse-stack](https://github.com/modernistik/parse-stack) to integrate Rails with a Parse Server. (Rails: 5.2.4.5; Ruby: 2.4.0; parse-stack: 1.8.1.)

I want to define attributes and methods on the `Parse::User` class, such that a `User` object `has_many` departments and a `User` can find its `department` as the first `Department` object in the list returned by `user.departments`.

Here's the class definition for `User`:

```
class Parse::User < Parse::Object # [1]

  attr_accessor :current_password, :password_confirmation, :role_display_name
  property      :role

  belongs_to    :hospital
  has_many      :conversations, field: :doctor
  has_many      :tokens, through: :relation
  has_many      :departments, through: :relation # [2]

  validates     :password, length: { is: 8 }

  def department
    self.departments.first  # [3]
  end

end

# [1] also tried defining `Doctor` as a subclass of `Parse::User`, or `Parse::Object`
# [2] tried `through: :array` as well
# [3] self.departments[0] gives an error in the console, using either :array or :relation
```

... but upon loading the `parse-console`, running `Parse.auto_generate_models!`, and selecting a doctor, I can't find their department with `doc.department`:

```
2.4.0 :003 > doc.department
NoMethodError: undefined method `department' for #<Parse::User:0x0055c07f892ef8>
Did you mean?  departments
               departments=
```

What fundamental concepts am I missing or getting wrong?

Comment: @engineersmnky, see my note (# [1]) in the class definition—I did try to make a `Doctor < Parse::Object` subclass as well, with the same results. Also, Ruby allows you to re-open a class definition for purposes like this.

Comment: I know how ruby works. I do not know how parse stack works thus the question. There is no immediately discernible reason as to why the instance method `department` is not recognized as a method definition in this context. For Example: https://replit.com/@engineersmnky/CultivatedLeanSource#main.rb

Comment: So looking into it a bit more I think your issue is the usage of `Parse.auto_generate_models!` can you confirm your definition of `Parse::User` is actually being loaded because it appears that Parse is not seeing it and rather just generating a class based on your Parse schema. [Source](https://github.com/modernistik/parse-stack/blob/v1.8.0/lib/parse/model/core/builder.rb#L51)